# What are the sample_weight parameter in various performance metrics

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn

Can someone explain what is the sample_weight parameter for in various scikit-learn performance metrics such as:

- accuracy score (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)
- Jaccard_score (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score)
- F1-score (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)
  etc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply indicates how much each smaple affects the metric. Look at this example:

With below `y_true` and `y_pred` the `accuracy_score` would be `0.6666666`:

```
y_true = [0, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 1, 1]

accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred) # 0.6666666666666666
```

But if second sample is more important to us than other two, we can enforce it's significance with `sample_weight`:

```
accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=[1, 2, 1]) # 0.5
```

Comment: Many thanks for explaining this and including an example! This makes sense. Do you know in what situations/scenarios we would want to adjust the sample_weights?

Comment: most of all in case of imbalanced data in which you have significantly less samples in some classes, it would be good to know if  model has bias toward classes with more samples or not.